# Use Sum with count

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, postgresql-8.4

I look some answers but they don't responde me. Suppose this table

```
id_salesman id_product desc_product
1               2           Desk
2               3           Chair
2               4           Kitchen
3               2           Desk
3               2           Desk
```

i want to know the count of products saled, i try to sum a count function , but i can't
Result

```
id_salesman products_sales
1              1
2              2
3              2
```

Thanks!

Sorry about my english

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `group by` clause with `count` as below

```
select id_salesman, count(1) as products_sales
from salesman
group by id_salesman
```

Comment: I need a thing without group by, because it's a large query

Comment: What does it mean large query? Could you include the query to the question ?

Comment: i think that will give dezire result nice

Comment: @AmitSingh what do you mean by " that will give desired result?"

Answer (score 0):

Use group by on id_salesman field

```
select id_salesman, count(*) as products_sales from table
group by id_salesman
```

Here is link to [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9a81b/2)

Comment: What's the different between count (*) and count (1)

Comment: @Frechi There is absolutely no difference. Actually Count(1) is automatically converted to count(*)